# Change the background of li element using the html content of that element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

Im pretty sure this is possible, I think Im on the right track, yet it still isn't working for me;
I have this as the jquery, have imported the latest jquery file - what I want is for each colour list item, the content that they contain will be used as their background colour.
If anyone can help me, as I have tried for tens of hours with no success, thank you.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$( "$li.selected-color" ).each(function(element) { var colorlinkcontent = $(element).html(); $(element).css("background-color", colorlinkcontent); });
</script>
<ul class="colors">
  <li class="selected-color">#f334568
    <li class="selected-color">#f334568
      <li class="selected-color">#f334568
        <li class="selected-color">#f334568
</ul>
<hr/>
<span class="title">Selected criteria:</span>

<ul class="selected-criteria">
  <li>yolo
    <li class="selected-color">#f334568
      <li>Website
</ul>
```

Comment: First off, your markup is invalid - no closing tags. `</script>` has no opening tag. `$( "$li.selected-color" )` must be `$( "li.selected-color" )`. Plz fix them which may as well fix your probelm!

Comment: here is a demo https://jsfiddle.net/psg3a8bb/

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

1. No `li` closing tags.
2. No `script` opening tag.
3. The hex colour codes have too many digits.
4. The script tag needs to wait until the DOM is loaded or go after the list elements.
5. You need to read how [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) works as the first argument of the callback function is the index not the element.
6. The selector should be `li.selected-color` rather than `$li.selected-color`.

```html
<ul class="colors">
  <li class="selected-color">#f33456</li>
  <li class="selected-color">#f33456</li>
  <li class="selected-color">#f33456</li>
  <li class="selected-color">#f33456</li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<span class="title">Selected criteria:</span>

<ul class="selected-criteria">
  <li>yolo</li>
  <li class="selected-color">#f33456</li>
  <li>Website</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( "li.selected-color" ).each( function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.css( "background-color", $el.text() );
});
</script>
```